# Mongoose Chained Queries

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, functional-programming

I'm currently reading [this excellent MDN tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose#using_models).

There seems to be two main different ways to perform queries with mogoose, one being more 'functional', using a chained notation.
My question is, does this kind of notation starting with an empty `.find()` method starts to import all the collection, then filters the successive pointers inside the app, or does it compile the query (the filtering stuff happening on the mongoDB instance) and only performs the callback locally?

The dot-based notation looks nice and cleaner, but if the filter does not get compiled before requests are being made it seems to be a bad idea to import the whole collection on the app for every simple query. Am I right?

If this is the case, are we in one of these situation where we have to favour object composition over function composition (like Eric Elliott said), or is it not the point here?

Comment: Of course the whole collection is not imported in the app. Imagine your entire 10 GB database being loadad in memory for each request. Your Mongoose query gets transformed into a native MongoDB one and passed to the driver. The database engine does the job and then returns the matching documents only.

Comment: The find() call creates and returns a query object, but it doesn't actually execute the query - unless you pass it a callback. You can then chain other method calls on this query to refine or modify it. When it's all ready, you execute it - with exec() or then().